# How to display JSON data from API in TableView?

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, uitableview

I recieves json data from api and totally confused what should I do next to pass this data to custom cell with imageView and labels in order to update UI in tableView.

Getting JSON

```
import Foundation

struct Breed: Codable {
    let name: String?
    let origin: String?
    let life_span:String?
    let temperament: String?
    let description: String?
    let wikipedia_url: String?
    let image: Image?
}

struct Image: Codable {
    let url: String?
}

func getDataFromCatsApi() {
    
    let url = URL(string: "https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/breeds")
    
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { data, _ , error in
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        if let data = data {
            let breed = try? decoder.decode([Breed].self, from: data)
            print (breed as Any)
        } else {
            print (error as Any)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

All data is printed correctly.

In ViewController I have a tableView with custom cell.

```
    import UIKit

class MainVC: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        title = "Cats"
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        getDataFromCatsApi()
        
    }
}

extension MainVC: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell",
                                                 for: indexPath) as? CustomTableViewCell
        
        return cell ?? CustomTableViewCell()
    }
}
```

Class for custom cell. Here I have imageView and labels for displaying data from json.

```
    import UIKit

class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var catImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var originLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var addToFavButton: UIButton!

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are not returning anything from `getDataFromCatsApi().` Since it is an asynchronous call, you have to implement a way to get the values either by using a callback or a delegate. In this case callback would suffice.

Then once you receive a value from the api call, set those values in `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` in which you can use `cell.nameLabel.text = <received value>` and etc.

Answer (score 0):

First of all declare only those properties as optional which can be `nil`

```
struct Breed: Decodable {
    let name, origin, lifeSpan, temperament, description: String
    let wikipediaUrl: String?
    let image: Image?
}

struct Image: Decodable {
    let url: String?
}
```

In `getDataFromCatsApi` add a completion handler

```
func getDataFromCatsApi(completion:  @escaping (Result<[Breed],Error>) -> Void ) {
    
    let url = URL(string: "https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/breeds")
    
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { data, _ , error in
        if let error = error { completion(.failure(error)); return }
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
        completion(Result { try decoder.decode([Breed].self, from: data!) })
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

In `MainVC` declare a data source array

```
var cats = [Breed]()
```

Replace `viewDidLoad` with

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    title = "Cats"
    view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
    getDataFromCatsApi {[unowned self] result in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            switch result {
                case .success(let breed): 
                    self.cats = breed
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                case .failure(let error): print(error)
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

and the table view datasources methods with

```
extension MainVC: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return cats.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell",
                                                 for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
        
        let cat = cats[indexPath.row]
        cell.nameLabel = cat.name
        cell.originLabel = cat.origin
    }
}
```

To load the pictures is beyond the scope of the question. There are libraries like SDWebImage or Kingfisher to load and cache images asynchronously.

Answer (score -1):

I have attached the code please check

```
extension MainVC: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return Breed.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell",
                                                 for: indexPath) as? CustomTableViewCell
        cell.nameLabel.text  = Breed[indexPath.row].name // see here
        
        return cell ?? CustomTableViewCell()
    }
}
```

Comment: I have crash due to nil found in 'var Breed: [Breed]!'

Answer (score -1):

```
func changeApiKey(tbale:UITableView,completionHandler: @escaping(GetNurti) -> Void) {
    if let url = URL(string: "https://app.omana-app.com/api/nutritionists_listing") {
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.setValue("text/plain",forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        request.addValue("sk_d3KmPtjEtdGTjChLB0ylraAb/AWgfyR9MOxFXwgEWSZsnpoIXFVDfm1Snoak0ufRe0w=", forHTTPHeaderField: "secret_key")
        request.addValue("pk_Bvk6rVC7WxbRW2O3sy4xwCEiM+n8jdT55BQv4BA0zG4IawzpbDhTVzSvj43DcvU7cM0x", forHTTPHeaderField: "publish_key")
        request.addValue("Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJkYXRhIjp7ImlkIjoxODQsImxvZ2luX3RpbWUiOiIxNzAxMTcxNTMwIn0sImlhdCI6MTcwMTE3MTUzMH0.nnTCXPkr5SxAtnclkEi-WyEDzzfvOzG9zyplFu5TsBo", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard error == nil else {
                print(error!)
                return
            }
            guard let jsonData = data else { return }
            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let productsResponse = try decoder.decode(GetNurti.self, from: jsonData)
                let productDetails = productsResponse
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    //self.tblData = productDetails.body?.nutritionistsList
                    tbale.reloadData()
                }
                

                completionHandler(productDetails)
            }catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }

        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).